# I am trying to send a POST request to an external server from a Cloud function to a non google server

Tags: javascript, firebase

this is my function which is triggered by a webhook using Axios. what it's doing is just bringing a response of all the payments in the system rather than adding a payment into the system.
Please assist.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); 
// Get the default instance
const axios = require('axios')
var querystring = require("querystring");
var http = require("http");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.afterPayments = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });

  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    response.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.status(204).send("");
  } else {
  }

  console.log(request.body);

  var secretHash =
    "6*****";
  
    let config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization:
            '****** ',
        }
      }
  const data = {
    customer_id: request.body.data.customer.id,
    payment_method: "20",
    receipt_number: request.body.data.tx_ref,
    date: request.body.data.created_at,
    amount: request.body.data.amount,
    field_1: "",
    field_2: "",
    field_3: "",
    field_4: "",
    field_5: "",
  };

  async function recordPayment() {
    await axios
      .post("http://********************/admin/finance/payments", data,config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(`Status: ${response.status}`);
        console.log("Body: ", response.data);
        response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        response.send(err);
      });
  }

  recordPayment();
});
```

If I use my application using the same code, it's running properly, but when I use the cloud function it's not going through.

I am seeing the same issue when I use postman to make the same request, it does the same thing as that cloud function.

is there somethingn that i am missing on the server to server POST request.

Comment: `it's not going through` what do you see in the developer console? - note you should be doing `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST"` not multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` like you do - however, that looks wrong, unless the code you presented is server code not client code

Comment: that's the code that I hosted on the google Cloud Function. - note the connection is there, between the server I am sending the POST request to and the cloud function, the problem is when I send that request it is giving me a response of all the payments instead of creating the payment into the system. But if I use my flutter application using `postData()` and the same logic it's creating the payment.